# Why does jQuery .css('left') and .position().left return different values?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, jquery-animate

The values I'm getting for `$(el).css('left')` and `$(el).position().left` are different?

If I go `$(el).css('left', '100px')`, then `$(el).css('left')` it returns `110px` instead of `100px` (yes, it is always 10% more) and if I evaluate `$(el).position().left`, it gives me `100`.

Why does Chrome behave this way? You can see how this would affect jQuery animations using the `left` property.

I'm using Chrome 21.0.1180.57 on Ubuntu.

EDIT 1: Seems to be only affecting Chrome, FF 14.0.1 is giving me the same values.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `left` returns calculated value of the CSS left property.

`position().left` returns the x-coordinate relative to the element's first offset parent.

These values [can be equal](http://jsfiddle.net/LgFD6/1/) and  they can be [not equal](http://jsfiddle.net/LgFD6/) .

`position().left` can also easily be [different between browsers](http://jsfiddle.net/LgFD6/2/) because of different rendering whereas `.css("left")` can only differ in the units given, if that.

Comment: Except that `.css("left")` isn't doing that! http://i.imgur.com/auymh.png On chrome, `.position().left` is giving me the CSS `left` property value.

Comment: @GauravDadhania can you show me a jsfiddle of that? In the screenshot, they have different values. One is 1145 other is 1040.

Comment: Hmm, I tried to recreate it, but the markup/styling is too complicated. However, eventually, changing the `position` of `div.jspDrag` from `relative` to `absolute` fixed it! Now I get the actual `left` property when I use `.css("left")`. Do you know why `position: relative` was the culprit?

Comment: @GauravDadhania when absolutely positioned, `style.left` should be equal to `position().left` because the element is out of document flow and nothing affects its positioning but its offset parent and `.style.left`. When the element is affected by flow, there are more things than just `.style.left` that affect its final position in document as is shown in my jsfiddles.

Comment: Oh yes, I get that, but in either case `.css("left")` should return the CSS `left` property value. As you can see in the screenshot, when the element was relatively positioned, `.css("left")` was returning something different. Based on your JSFiddles, `.position().left` should be affected, `.css("left")` should always return the CSS property value.

Answer (score 3):

Try this code :

```
$("#div")[0].style.left
```